# Verizon Fios Wireless router and ethernet outlets in various rooms of the house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have Verizon FIOS and with that a Verizon wireless router (in a closet upstairs) in which the 4 ethernets ports are connected to a panel where there are 4 ethernet ports. Each port from that panel is wired to a specific room in the house.

There is one ethernet outlet downstairs in which I have 1 ethernet cable connected to the 1 to a D-Link Whole-Home Router 1000, Wireless-N (DIR-645).

I forgot what I did a few years back but I connected the cable to the D link because I wanted to use the multiple ethernet ports on that router to basically plug a few devices (cable, xbox, ps4) so they can be hardwired to the internet. I originally was going to have those devices connect wirelessly to the Verizon router upstairs but the signal is very weak.

My questions is if there is a way i can still have the same setup but have the D link also broadcast the internet wirelessly downstairs so that wireless signal would be strong there as well.

If not any suggestions on a better solution in which i can still have the devices already hardwired still eb hardwired but somehow boost the wireless signal from upstairs to downstairs.

I bought this NETGEAR N150 Wi-Fi Range Extender for Mobile - Wall Plug Version (WN1000RP) and plugged it into various outlets downstairs and upstairs but that does not seem to work since the signal downstairs was still bad.

Thank you and appreciate the time

-Rod

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to set your dlink to rebroadcast your fios wifi. I would check the settings on the dlink  for this option.

Comment: Thanks. One thing to note is that the ethernet cable is plugged into the one of the ethernet 1-4 ports. I would have assumed that from the wall it would go into WAN port on the dlink router. In any case I will look for any rebroadcast setting.

Comment: Almost correct. @RodneyVallo Disable DHCP on your D-Link if you haven’t done so yet. Then, simply enable the wireless network. You can set it to the same name and security settings to enable roaming between the two networks.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! So I can leave the setup as is with the devices hardwired to the dlink router and just adjust the settings on the router as you had mentioned?

Comment: yes. you do not need to use the wan port on your dlink in this instance

Comment: Run LAN downstairs and connect a router to that.

Comment: @ramhound do i run the lan through the d link?

Comment: **you connect it to the router**

Comment: @Ramhound He already has. Rodney Vallo Yes. Just enable WiFi and enjoy.